# Can we run MS Access Macros by PHP?

Tags: php

I have ms access file containing macro and when I run macro that macro insert data from T1 table to T2 and T3 Tables.

So my question is can we run this ms access macro by php ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. You need to be compiled on Windows, and access the Access database using the [COM (Common Object Model)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.com.php) layer. Once there, there is a method for running macros [runMacro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192075.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I think no, the macros are executed by the Access windows application. Via php you have only a driver that can read/write on db tables